# @Import @Configuration only if NOT already available in parent configuration

Tags: java, spring

I've got the situation that I have to load a child application context, where I don't know if certain configurations are already loaded by the parent application context. In order to not instantiate services twice I want to load only @Configuration classes that are not already present in the parent application context.

I've already implemented an ImportSelector that checks the parent application context. This works, but fails with transitive dependencies declared via @Import on @Configuration classes loaded in the child application context. With an ImportSelector I can check if a @Configuration is already in the parent application context, but if it is not, then I've found no way to prevent that an @Import'ed class on the @Configuration to be added is NOT imported into the child context because it's already available in the parent context.

Any help is welcome!

Thanks!
Peter

Comment: This works, but fails with transitive dependencies: to solve this you can loop over all the child contexts and check for same in the same way you did for the parent context.

Comment: The problem is that once I detect, that a configuration is not in the parent context, I want to include it in the child context. And once I include it in the child context it loads the imported configuration in the child context - even if it already is in the parent context